# =importhtml Google Sheets table

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

Unfortunately I don't know how to source this and was wondering if someone could show me how. I am trying to learn hear so the correct answer is great, but the "How to get the answer" is more important to me.

I am using google sheets, and looking to bring in a table or data point from a website. I know =importhtml works for this but I don't know how to tell it what to get, I just keep getting people giving me the answers instead of the how too.

The current one I am looking for is the website "https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/TSLA/earnings/" Using TSLA as the example stock. I am looking to bring in the table that has all the earnings dates. The header is "TESLA (NASDAQ:TSLA) EARNINGS HISTORY BY QUARTER". I am just looking for all the dates in that table, but if it is easier to bring in the whole table I'll do that instead. But I know these websites update and that can change how the =importhtml works, so I would like to be able to fix it myself.

Also I am on a Mac

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
=index(IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/TSLA/earnings/","table",2),,1)
```

"2" is the table index for the one you are looking for and "1" is the column that you need.

Delete 1 and you will get the whole table.

```js
=index(IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/TSLA/earnings/","table",2))
```